# How to connect Nest in Europe

Tags: hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I found a question regarding the Nest thermostat [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/12620/would-the-nest-thermostat-work-outside-us). But that is only a question "Will it work?". Thanks to that I know it **WILL**, the problem is...**HOW**. I know the wire naming conventions are different etc, and also that there is a "OpenTherm" protocol over which thermostat and boiler are communicating.

I found a way how to supply the Nest thermostat with separate transformator power supply(24V) and I hooked up a relay on heating and it simply does not work. My question is, can Nest do this and if so, how should I connect it in order to make it work?

Comment: What wires wires do you have now (colors and/or labels)? What terminals do they go into on your existing thermostat? I just happened to read an article recently that covers [how to get NEST set up in Europe](http://motote.blogspot.ca/2012/09/nest-thermostat-in-europe-hacks.html) and also [how to hack NEST to show correct location](http://motote.blogspot.com.es/2012/09/nest-thermostat-in-europe-hacks-ii.html). Note that this is NOT a supported config, and the guy is using network hacks to trick the NEST to act how he wants. Help with the network/software part is beyond scope of this site.

Comment: That is a great article, however, I connected nest directly to boiler where it should operate with relay and I am not sure whether Nest copes with that or it has to have some standard protocol, such as OpenTherm...?

Comment: This is a question for the manufacturer.  Brand specific advice is off topic here. See the [faq].

Comment: I found three other questions regarding Nest. None of them is closed for being off-topic. I didn't think about looking in faq two months ago since none of them had been closed.

Answer (score -2):

Check out my blog,

Humble, just trying to share my experience implementing nest on a 220 240 v system

http://usingnestthermostatineurope.wordpress.com/

Comment: -1. Answers that rely on a link don't work well on SE, since links can go bad over time. Please make sure the post here answers the question and only uses links for added detail. See the [faq] for more information.

Comment: See also the [section on self promotion](http://diy.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion)